# Node + jQuery Beginner - How to use jQuery after installing it via npm

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a node server set up and have installed jQuery using the following command:

> npm install jquery

I am a beginner to Node and wanted to know how to actually put jQuery to use when it is installed by npm. Is it just as easy as linking the files in the head of the web page just like we would link it on a static HTML page?

I want to use it develop a simple web page with some bootstrap designing

Comment: You can use Browserify.

Answer (score 4):

just insert it in your html code like this

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the same thing goes for bootstrap if you want to download it via npm